# Wrong use of joins on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problems to get the correct data from a table which holds different types of records, and I want to count how many of each I've got.

This is a simpler schema:

```
companies:

| id | name     |
|----|----------|
| 1  | company1 |
| 2  | company2 |



messages:

| id | type    | text  | companies_id |
|----|---------|-------|--------------|
| 1  | request | blah  | 1            |
| 2  | report  | blah! | 1            |
| 3  | request | foo   | 2            |
| 4  | request | bar   | 2            |
| 5  | report  | hi!   | 2            |
```

And a link to the SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7237f/6

Note that if I only use one join, to get the total of just one message type for any company, it works:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(m1.id) as requests
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN messages m1 ON m1.companies_id = c.id AND m1.type = 'request' 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

It won't if I try to list the total for all the message types on any company, like I'm doing here:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(m1.id) as requests, COUNT(m2.id) as reports
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN messages m1 ON m1.companies_id = c.id AND m1.type = 'request' 
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON m2.companies_id = c.id AND m2.type = 'report' 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

What am I doing wrong? I think there must be a way to do it using joins instead of nested queries, which I guess would be pretty slower.

Comment: LEFT JOIN only once. Use case expressions in the COUNT to do conditional counting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` only once. Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting

```
SELECT c.*,
       SUM(case when m1.type = 'request' then 1 else 0 end) as requests,
       SUM(case when m1.type = 'report' then 1 else 0 end) as reports
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN messages m1 ON m1.companies_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: I think this is a very best answer.

Comment: I've tried execution times and this is definitely faster than using more than one join. Thanks a lot!

Comment: SQL wizard equivalent: `COUNT(m1.type = 'request' OR NULL) AS requests,` `COUNT(m1.type = 'report' OR NULL) AS reports`.  This works because `COUNT()` counts non-null values, and *`expr OR NULL`* is a boolean expression with only two possible values, `TRUE` if *expr* is true... otherwise `NULL`.  The `TRUE` rows are counted.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, that may work for MySQL, but is not valid ANSI SQL syntax - which is what I try to write (when possible.)

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is no required for two different joins;

```
SELECT 
c.id, 
sum(case when m1.type = 'request' then 1 else 0 end) as requests,
sum(case when m1.type = 'report' then 1 else 0 end) as reports
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN messages m1 ON m1.companies_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: Hey!, thanks for your reply. It's the right one. But someone else replied just the same before.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to just count the distinct IDs:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(DISTINCT m1.id) as requests, COUNT(DISTINCT m2.id) as reports
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN messages m1 ON m1.companies_id = c.id AND m1.type = 'request' 
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON m2.companies_id = c.id AND m2.type = 'report' 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: It works! However, I've checked that other solutions provided with just one join are faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your query as to get different counts based on your types with single join clause

```
SELECT c.*,
SUM(m.type = 'request') as requests,
SUM(m.type = 'report')  as reports
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.companies_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

In Mysql if `sum` is used conditional expression it will return as a boolean 0/1 based on if condition is met or not

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7237f/11)

Comment: Relying on implicit cast from bool to int is bound to go wrong eventually!

Comment: @TFD *Relying on implicit cast from bool to int* why this expression will be cast to int ?

Comment: It gives the correct totals except for cases of companies not having any message, which makes NULL, instead of 0. The solution provided by @jarlh works around that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid an aggregate SUM of boolean would result in a boolean result, which is pointless, so it is cast. In MySQL case it goes to decimal or double IIRC, check the docs on MySQL aggregates. Good code shows actual intent, and does not rely on code hacks

Comment: @TFD Can you provide the reference links(official docs) which says *aggregate SUM of boolean would result in a boolean result* i am bit confused how that can be if a boolean 1 is added to another boolean 1 like (1+1) how can it result as a boolean 1 ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid read MySQL docs on aggregates, there is no way it SUMs booleans, it will sum int, doubles etc. IIRC x86 only adds int, double etc too, so it would be some funky code otherwise